# Why does cooking oil solidify

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am in a tropical climate. The vegetable cooking oil I buy remains liquid for about 3 or 4 months and by the time I'm finishing a container, it has solidified.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to avoid this?

---

*It appears to be palm oil. Yes it liquefies again although in my case, it solidifes again. I warm it up every night before cooking supper.*

Comment: What kind of oil exactly? That may be important. Also, does it liquefy back upon heating?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: It appears to be palm oil. Yes it liquefies again although in my case, it solidifes again. I warm it up every night before cooking supper :)

Comment: Palm oil has reported freezing point 35 deg C and minimal recommended storage temp 50 deg C ( to keep it as oil ).

Comment: Worth noting that many oils only freeze only *slowly* even if the temperature is lower than their freezing point. Palm oil may only freeze slowly even at 30°. Olive oil often slowly freezes at ambient temperatures in the UK.

Comment: @matt_black I assume oils have high tendency to be supercooled. I have added such a note. I also assume some oils may be oil mixtures with significantly lowered freezing point. ( Mixtures have frequently lower melting/freezing point than expected from linear interpolation for pure substances parameters)

Answer (score 5):

As revealed later, first check, if it is temperature dependent temporary solidification. It is natural and reversible process, the same process as when melted fat solidifies back when cooled down. Prevention is to keep oil warm enough and the cure is warming it up until it melts.

Every fat has its typical melting point ( or range). Solid fats melt at temperature higher than room one, vegetable oils melt at temperature lower than room one. Some fats are in this aspect in a gray zone, melting or freezing according to the current room temperature.

Note in the table below **palm oil has exceptionally high freezing point**  $\pu{35 ^{\circ}C}$. If solidification is an issue, consider using other oil with lower melting point. Oils have tendency to be supercooled (hesitating to start freezing up), so it may need lower than expected temperature to observe solidification, that may be triggered by random events.

I also assume some oils may be oil mixtures with lowered freezing point. .

See below the table  [digeoris.com: Freezing Point of Vegetable Oil](https://digeoris.com/blog/optimal-temperatures-for-freezing-vegetable-and-animal-fats/)

| Oil or fat | Freezing / melting point °C | Transport min °C | Transport max °C | Storage min °C | Storage max °C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Castor oil | -3 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 |
| Coconut oil | 25 | 27 | 32 | 40 | 45 |
| Cottonseed oil | 48 | Ambient | Ambient | 20 | 25 |
| Linseed oil | -24 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Maize (corn) oil | -11 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Olive oil | -6 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Palm oil | 35 | 32 | 40 | 50 | 55 |
| Canola (rapeseed)oil | -10 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Safflower oil | -17 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Sesame oil | -6 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |
| Sheanut butter | 34-38 | 38 | 41 | 50 | 55 |
| Soybean oil | -16 | Ambient | Ambient | 20 | 25 |
| Sunflower oil | -17 | Ambient | Ambient | 15 | 20 |

---

If the above does not apply:

It probably polymerizes due present double bonds, reacting with air oxygen, being a vegetable oil. Famous for this is lineseed oil, that is used in oil paints.

I suggest keeping oil stocks in cold place, as the reaction is slower at lower temperature. If applicable, even in fridge, where it may  temporarily freeze ( and melt back when warmed up in a room).

And/or it may be more applicable to buy smaller oil packages or divide their content in several smaller vessels, kept closed, cold if possible, taken sequentially. The remaining vessels would not then be repeatedly exposed to air and if possible, would be staying in cold place.

Comment: Assuming implicit chemistry skills of the OP, I have intentionally written this rather from point of view of a cook than a chemist. So both answers may complement each other.

Comment: For some reason I can't mark this answer as accepted. There seems to be some problem with the stackexchange interface. Will contact stackexchange staff about it, please be patient!

Answer (score 4):

Cooking oils are consist of esters of [fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid). Some of them are saturated, others are unsaturated; the later refers to the presence of one, or multiple $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds.  An example for this later is [oleic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleic_acid):

[image]

(image credit: English edition of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleic_acid)).

Over time, promoted by heat (not only cooking, ambient temperature suffice given enough time), sun light, and traces of metal salts of these fatty acids, exposure to air leads to polymerization.  Oxygen (about $\pu{21 vol\%}$ in air) is a diradical, which can attack these double bonds.  Eventually, individual molecules with $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds then cross-link with each other on expense of these double bonds.  So

- the $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds are consumed
- individual small molecules bind with each other on positions of former $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds
- the new molecules formed are larger
- compared to the starting material, the newly formed products have a higher melting and boiling temperature.

Because cooking oil is a blend of compounds, oleic acid isn't the only compound undergoing this reaction.  Then, the hardened cooking oil equally is a blend of multiple chemicals, too.  The principle is not restricted to cooking, though.  In painting, this process is triggered by intentional addition of a [siccatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drying_agent), compounds known to accelerate this process.