Oxygen as polymerisation initiator
In my chemistry textbook, when talking about polymerisation, there was a small section about the discovery of polyethylene that was as follows:

The chemists put some ethene in a container at 170C and 1900 atm. They did not know the container had a leak and so traces of oxygen (which was later proved to be an initiator for the polymerisation) were present in the ethene sample. The next day, a thin layer of white solid was found in the container.

Can someone explain how oxygen acts as the polymerisation initiator? Is it related to how oxygen can react with undisturbed diethyl ether to form diethyl ether hydroperoxide?

Just like other radicals.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/170484/9961
